# Using OS X standard cursors in Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I found a bunch of OS X cursors in:
`/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HiServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/cursors`

Each cursor is a directory with two files: `cursor.pdf` and `info.plist`

It includes useful things such openhand, zoomin, zoomout, and many others. Is there a way to access these in Tkinter? Or, alternatively, is there a way to use an image as a cursor in Tkinter? It only needs to work in OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `cursor=` argument when defining a widget, and it will display the proper cursor depending on your operating system. For example, the following Python 3 code creates a simple window that uses the `cross` cursor with a button that will change the cursor to `plus` on hover:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.config(cursor='cross')
root.geometry('600x400')

testButton = tk.Button(root, text='Hover over here!', cursor='plus')
testButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You can find a list of built-in cursors for all platforms [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/cursors.htm), but you can scroll down to find the list of Mac specific cursors.

As for custom cursors, you could create a .cur file with an image processor and then apply it to a widget with `cursor='@filename.cur'`, just be sure that the .cur file is in the same directory as your script.

Comment: I got the Mac specific cursors to work, but the .cur files seem to be ignored.

Comment: @Eduardo Hi, I can't seem to reproduce the problem, I created a sample cursor from [link](http://www.cursor.cc/) and it was able to replace the default cursor. It may be a problem caused by specific mac and tkinter versions that prevents the cursor from showing up.

Comment: Yes, it works with the cursors I create there too. It still does not work with cursors I create from .png. Probably a bug in the conversion. But this will do. Thanks!